# Webpack compress path names

Tags: webpack

Is their a webpack plugin that can change the output string paths to be shorter paths without clashing i.e. `./node_modules/module_a` -> `./n/a`.

In the output file which is already minified I have lots of reference that look like this `n("./node_modules/core-js/modules/_to-length.js")` even if all occurrences of node_modules can be replaced with `n`, I can save around 15kb of final size.

Answer (score 0):

`node_modules` is already present in the resolve path for webpack by default.
`require('module_a')` would look it up in the node modules directory if such a module is not present in root path.

One more thing you could do is use the resolve alias

```
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        'jQuery': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js'),
        'core_modules':path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/core_js/modules')
      }
    }
```

Webpack will resolve "core_modules" to the path provided for imports

Further you can use [string replacement plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-webpack-plugin) or [write your own plugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/how-to-write-a-plugin.html) to do what is required!

Answer (score 0):

I posted a similar question to yours (linked) and realized that by disabling the NamedModulesPlugin in the Webpack config, it'll actually just remove the reference paths altogether from the output (no need to mangle them to something shorter).