# Minifying import paths for modules in webpack

Tags: webpack-2

I've got a TypeScript project that uses Webpack successfully to yield ES6, which is run through babel-minify to tree-shake it and produce a significantly smaller bundle output file.

This file appears to contain all the logic from my own program as well as the logic for each of the pieces of the imported libraries I'm using (e.g. rxjs, lodash, etc.)

However, I'm looking through the generated file and it appears that at the top we've got some webpack logic, then a map of the path of the original import to a function that implements it, and well, really a lot of that all the way down, with various portions pointing to dependencies and their path strings.

Now, given that everything is self-contained within this webpack bundle (no other chunks), the inclusion of all the source file names seems to take up a lot of space needlessly.

For example, I'm looking at one section in here for lodash's isBoolean script:

```
"./node_modules/lodash/isBoolean.js": function(e, t, o) {
    var r = o("./node_modules/lodash/_baseGetTag.js"),
        s = o("./node_modules/lodash/isObjectLike.js");
    e.exports = function(e) {
        return !0 === e || !1 === e || s(e) && "[object Boolean]" == r(e)
    }
},
```

Now, it seems like there are a lot of characters being taken up to describe the source file. Since there's no actual dependency at this time on the source file, why can't each key just be replaced with a shorter string identifier throughout, as in the following example:

```
"a": function(e, t, o) {
    var r = o("b"),
        s = o("c");
    e.exports = function(e) {
        return !0 === e || !1 === e || s(e) && "[object Boolean]" == r(e)
    }
},
```

where "a", "b", and "c" are all representative of each place where the original string values occur throughout the entire bundle. This shouldn't impact all strings, but rather just the import file path strings.

There appears to be someone asking a similar question at [Webpack compress path names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055935/webpack-compress-path-names) who didn't really get a satisfactory answer, in my opinion.

Is there some option or plugin I can use that could mangle the module path names?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after reading through Webpack's source code and figuring out how it actually assembles the whole thing.

I had the NamedModulesPlugin in my config (likely an artifact from one of the various quickstarts out there) and this plugin inserts all the module paths into the output.

Commenting that out (or just removing it) from the config removes it entirely from the output (no mangling necessary).